# Cloudera CDH can not start yarn timeline server for tez-ui

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh, apache-tez

When I enable the yarn time server by adding the configurations to yarn-site.xml in Cloudera Manager Advanced Configuration Options:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.hostname</name>
  <value>yarn-hostname</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.generic-application-history.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.ttl-enable</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name> yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
</property>
```

then restart the cluster,but timeline server not start.How to solve the problem?What is the mechanism of CM Managing hadoop? I can not find any timeline log in yarn logs.

CDH version is CDH-5.3.6-1.cdh5.3.6.p0.11,hadoop version is 2.5.0.

Comment: Tez does not comes with Cloudera distribution, it is related to Hortonworks. Is your question related to timeline server or tez?

Comment: My question is why I can not enable timeline server in CDH.

Comment: Is yarn-hostname valid ip or alias?

Comment: It is an alias. In this question,considering the confidentiality,I use it to replace the real host name.

Comment: Any luck on this? We're facing the same problem using CDH 5.4.5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start timeline server, connect to your yarn node,and run command below:

```
yarn timelineserver
```

... then you will start it. if you want to start with you own config, you can edit yarn-site.xml in CM.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.